# Grey box when trying to set latitude and longitude on Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My Google Map object displays as a grey box after setting the latitude and longitude to a variable named 'myLatLng'. I've tried setting to separate variables for latitude and longitude and it worked just fine then but from what I understand, this should be able to work using geometry.location only as in the code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({address: "Windsor, ON"}, function(results) {
            var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8, 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng), 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map").get(0), mapOptions);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results[0].geometry.location is already a google.maps.LatLng.  This doesn't work (the google.maps.LatLng constructor expects 2 numbers as arguments):

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng)
```

Just use it as is:

```
center: myLatLng
```

working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({address: "Windsor, ON"}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8, 
            center: myLatLng, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map").get(0), mapOptions);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width:500px;"></div>
```